# How to speed up the convergence?

Tags: numerical-methods

I should you Aitken's method and
the following formula :

$T_n = S_n - \dfrac{{A_{n+1}}^2}{A_{n+1}-A_{n+2}}$

in order to speed up 
$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (0.99)^k $

Please, help!

Comment: What does $S_n$, $A_n$ mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay even though this question isn't well posed, let me present an answer under the following assumptions.

You refear to the Aitken's method that is presented here in [wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aitken%27s_delta-squared_process#Definition)
Dooes your method equal the following?
$$ Ax_n=x_n-\frac{(\Delta x_n)^2}{\Delta^2 x_n}$$
Where $\Delta x_{n}={(x_{n+1}-x_{n})},\ $
and
$\Delta^2 x_n=x_n -2x_{n+1} + x_{n+2}.$ At least, this is how it is written in wiki.
If so, your $S_n$ corresponds to $x_n$ and your $A_n$ to $\Delta x_n$ and $T_n$ to $Ax_n$.
Note that you have a $+$ between the two terms an wiki a $-$. Without any further information I don't know how to handle that, so I take the approach from wiki.
$$\Delta x_n = x_{n+1} -x_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}0.99^k-\sum_{k=1}^{n}0.99^k=0.99^{n+1}$$
Furthermore
$$\Delta^2 x_n = x_{n+2} -x_{n+1} -x_{n+1}+x_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n+2}0.99^k-\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}0.99^k-\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}0.99^k+\sum_{k=1}^{n}0.99^k
\\= 0.99^{n+2}-0.99^{n+1}=(0.99-1)0.99^{n+1}=-0.01\cdot 0.99^{n+1}
$$
Therefore
$$
\frac{(\Delta x_n)^2}{\Delta^2 x_n}=\frac{0.99^{2n+2}}{-0.01\cdot0.99^{n+1}}
= -100\cdot 0.99^{n+1}
$$
And
$$
Ax_n=x_n-\frac{(\Delta x_n)^2}{\Delta^2 x_n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}0.99^k+100\cdot 0.99^{n+1}
$$
It holds $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}=99$ by the convergence of geometric series. Now if we plug $n=1$ into $Ax_n$ we already get $Ax_1=99$ so we converge immediatly. But this is acutally no surprise.
$$
Ax_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}0.99^k+100\cdot 0.99^{n+1}= \frac{1-0.99^{n+1}}{1-0.99}-0.99^0+ 100\cdot 0.99^{n+1} = 99$$
So we have constant values for $Ax_n$. Note that the $0.99^0$ is due to the fact the most geometric series start at $k=0$.

Comment: yes, it should be "-" and you solution is perfect